# Bean Validation Through JPA Relationships

Tags: jsf-2, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, bean-validation

I would like to use Bean Validation to annotate constraints in my entities , now the question is, will the relationships on the entities be validated as well?. For example suppose I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "css_empresa")
public class Empresa extends EntidadContactable implements Serializable,
    Convert {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EMPRESA_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = ConstantesSecuencias.SEQ_EMPRESA)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMPRESA_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "cod_empresa", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "num_ruc", precision = 13)
private BigDecimal numRuc;

@Column(name = "num_rup", precision = 15)
private BigDecimal numRup;

@Column(name = "txt_direccion_web", length = 255)
private String txtDireccionWeb;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "txt_nombre", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String txtNombre;

@Column(name = "txt_observaciones", length = 255)
private String txtObservaciones;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cod_usuario")
private Usuario administrador;

// bi-directional many-to-one association to DireccionEmpresa
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<DireccionEmpresa> direccionEmpresas;
    --Rest of code ommited for brevity
```

and DireccionEmpresa entity is declared as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "css_direccion_empresa")
public class DireccionEmpresa implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DIREMPRESA_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = ConstantesSecuencias.SEQ_DIREMPRESA)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DIREMPRESA_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "cod_direccion_empresa", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long codDireccionEmpresa;

@Column(name = "sts_predeterminado", nullable = false, length = 1)
private String stsPredeterminado;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "txt_calle_principal", nullable = false, length = 120)
private String txtCallePrincipal;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "txt_calle_secundaria", length = 120)
private String txtCalleSecundaria;

@Column(name = "txt_descripcion", length = 120)
private String txtDescripcion;

@Column(name = "txt_informacion_adicional", length = 120)
private String txtInformacionAdicional;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "txt_numero", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String txtNumero;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "txt_sector", nullable = false, length = 60)
private String txtSector;
```

Now, the question is will DireccionEmpresa constraints be checked by BeanValidation when saving Empresa?? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the constraints at `DireccionEmpresa` won't be validated when persisting an instance of `Empresa`.

Generally a cascaded validation will only happen when a reference (such as a plain object reference or a list) is annotated with the [@Valid annotation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-validationroutine-graphvalidation), which isn't the case for `List<DireccionEmpresa> direccionEmpresas;`.

But even if that field was annotated with `@Valid` such a cascaded validation wouldn't be triggered in the JPA case as the JPA 2 spec says in section 3.6.1.2:

> Validation cascade (@Valid) must not occur for entity associations (single- or multi-valued). [... This guarantees] that [...] no entity will be validated more than once during a given flush cycle.

So the constraints at `DireccionEmpresa` will only be validated automatically when persisting an instance of that type.

Comment: So, I should iterate the references and persist each one, in order for the validation to happen?.

Comment: As you're using `CascadeType.ALL` the referenced objects will automatically be persisted when persisting an `Empresa` instance. This in turn will trigger their validation, so you don't have to do this on your own. The spec just ensures that the referenced objects are not validated twice upon persisting the object owning the reference and upon persisting the referenced object itself.

Comment: Ok, so my reference to related entities needs to be Annotated with the '@Valid' annotation. In other words:
'@Valid
'@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<DireccionEmpresa> direccionEmpresas;
will trigger validation for DireccionEmpresa when an Empresa object is persisted;this way any contraint exception will be captured by JPA/JSF(etc) in nested relationships. I got it right?

Comment: Almost :-) JPA will validate the constraints at `DireccionEmpresa` whenever an instance of this type is persisted. Due to the cascade type `ALL` this will be the case whenever you persist an `Empresa` instance. The `@Valid` annotation at the reference doesn't make a difference in this case, as it won't (and must not) be used by JPA/Bean Validation for performing a cascaded validation when persisting an `Empresa` instance as outlined above. Nevertheless I still recommend to add the `@Valid` annotation in order to trigger a cascaded validation when manually validating an `Empresa` instance.

Comment: I had the same problem. I added @Valid Annotation. Before i added, it does not validate the baean, now it validates the bean two times.. Why?