# @Valid annotation validates the bean several times

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, bean-validation

I had the same problem like [Bean Validation Through JPA Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774413/bean-validation-through-jpa-relationships). I added the `@Valid` annotation. Now it validates the bean several times and I get the error messages several times too.

Code example:

```
@Entity
public class Plan extends AbstractEntity {
    ...
    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Part getPart() {
        return part;
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Part extends AbstractEntity {
    ...
    @Valid
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "part", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<PRO> getProList() {
        return proList;
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
public class PRO extends AbstractEntity {
    ...
    @Valid
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pro", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Sample> getSamples() {
        return samples;
    }
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Sample extends AbstractEntity {
    ...
    @Basic
    @NotNull
    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    ...
}
```

For this example: I save Plan and i get same error message 4 times.

Comment: Your `Plan` class includes a `Getter` method for `Part`. Is it intentional?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, `Plan` class includes a getter for `Part` and `Part` class includes a getter for `Plan`. It is a bidirectional connection.

Comment: But where are your constraints? Which error message do you get multiple times?

Comment: @Hardy When I define a message like `@NotNull(message="{errorCount}")` for `count` then I get same message 4 times. And I get without `message="{errorCount}"` error messages `count: cannot be null`, `samples: cannot be null`, `proList: cannot be null` and `part: cannot be null`.

Comment: I don't understand your answer in full. What do you mean with "And I get without message="{errorCount}" error messages ..."? Can you show some code which creates the full object you validate? And if you for example have multiple Sample instances in the samples list and each of them have a null count you would indeed get the same error message multiple times. However, if you look at the whole constraints violation you would see that the path differs.